# I do not know why that create function was not in the class extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, baseadapter

I do not know why that create function was not in the class extends BaseAdapter.

I want pick image from gallery to imageview in custom listView.

I try to add a function "onActivityResult" after function "getView" is not working.

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final int REQUEST_GALLERY = 1;

    Context mContext;
    String[] strText1;

    TextView Text1;
    public static ImageView imgView;

    public CustomList(Context context, String[] strText1) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.strText1 = strText1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return strText1.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (view == null)
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

        Text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text1);
        Text1.setText(strText1[position]);

        imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_NoPhoto);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent
                        , "Select Picture"), REQUEST_GALLERY);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I try to add a function "onActivityResult" to the class "MainActivity" it work.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CustomList.REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                CustomList.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

If I want to function "onActivityResult" in the class "CustomList". How to do?

Comment: `onActivityResult ` method is from `Activity`, so it's not possible to override it inside any other class which is not extending `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`. but you can archive require task using either by [creating custom listener using interface](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners) or [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN'T**. `onActivityResult` is designed to work with classes that extends `Activity`, which is why it would work in your `MainActivity` class.